# Facebook RSS Feed big image

Tags: facebook, image, rss, feed

Helle every one,

I'm currently working with a Facebook page RSS feed and I need to retrieve images on it. 
the problem is that those images are just thumbnail. I would like to donwload the big one.

For exemple I have these feed : https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=126044397444435&format=rss20

I have this image on the feed : https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_s.jpg

But I would like this one : https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s320x320/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_n.jpg

How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Large image link above no longer works.
This works currently:
https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_n.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the URLs

```
https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_s.jpg
https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s320x320/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_n.jpg
```

The subdomain for the large image is fbcdn-sphotos-a instead of fbcdn-photos-a, it has a s320x320 directory name inserted before the filename, and the filename is suffixed with _n instead of _s

The 320x320 is a max size, the following url returns the image at 480 px height
    https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s480x480/393656_257350694313804_126044397444435_712409_344887174_n.jpg